# Eclipse hangs on adding Gradle nature

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

Running Eclipse 2019-06, with Buildship 3.1.2. Created a project from existing folder, and when adding gradle nature, Eclipse does some work and then gets stuck on "Importing root project: Run build". Already removed and reinstalled Gradle, removed and reinstalled Buildship, deleted ~/.gradle and /.gradle files, tried using both Gradle wrapper and the current version of Gradle (5.6.2). Nothing in .metadata/.log file of help.

Answer (score 5):

Found this message, however in ~/.gradle/daemon/5.6.2/daemon-*.logs:

Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle Terms of Service defined at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service. Do you accept these terms? [yes, no]

The answer seems to be to uncheck "Build Scans" under Gradle in Preferences.

Comment: So this is a bug in the gradle import process of the buildship plugin?

Comment: it may have been fixed; I have since moved on to latest eclipse and buildship and have not seen the issue again.

Comment: I am using latest SpringToolSuite installed only this week. It has shown same issue.
I guess it will not happen again if I can somehow run the gradle on that project folder by command line and answer yes for that question just once. The bug is that buildship plugin is unable to open a popup on GUI to ask our confirmation and pass our response back to gradle,

Answer (score 0):

I needed to Update the Buildship plugin in Eclipse and that fixed it.